# How can I get a facebook access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to play around with `pynder` but in order to do so, I need a facebook access token.

I've googled around, and made a facebook developer profile.  I have an app Id and app secret.  How can I go about getting what I need to create a session in `pynder`?

Comment: To get a user access token you use Facebook Login

Comment: @WizKid I tried that.  Returns an error saying it can't authenticate

Comment: Then you did something wrong and you need to show us what you did

Comment: @WizKid To clarify, do you mean use my Facebook login in pynder?  Or do I obtain the access token somewhere on the developer site?

Comment: I have no idea what pynder is. But the only way to get a user access token is to use Facebook Login.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is using OAUTH2. Basicly you have to redirect the user to facebook. He authorizes your app. Facebook redirects back to your site with a &code= Parameter.
You call an facebook endpoint an exchange the code to an access_token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

You can grab an access token out of https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

You should be able to change to your app and generate a token.